# How to view Google Cloud Datastore Region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Not using App Engine, using Datastore alone. The portal asks you to select a region while creating your first entity.

But how do you view the region it's running in after creation?

Answer (score 4):

Your datastore region is the same as that of your Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project. The Cloud Datastore documentation provides instructions on how to locate it:

[Viewing the location of your project.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations#viewing_the_location_of_your_project)

Comment: Thanks. My project doesn't have a location, the location is empty on the project settings page. The app engine dashboard doesn't display anything because I'm not using it. But "gcloud app describe" gives me the location I set while creating the datastore. It's strange behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Originally, Datastore was only accessible from App Engine. This is why, still now, the location setting for your Google Cloud Platform project applies to both Cloud Datastore and App Engine. When you select a location in either product, you set the location for your entire Google Cloud Platform project.

So when you create your first Datastore entity in a project (or when you create an App Engine application, whichever you do first) it'll ask you for a location. Under the hood it'll create an App Engine app (like `gcloud app create`) in the given location. That's why you can run `gcloud app describe` and get information (You may also notice it has created two Cloud Storage buckets, "project-name.appspot.com" and "staging.project-name.appspot.com" for your App Engine app). The developer Console's App Engine section doesn't display anything though since there's no actual App Engine code deployed.