# How to get the location/region of an Datastore instance

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

To call the `Datastore.export()` API I need to provide a GCS bucket name in the same region as the Datastore I'm exporting.

I checked with node.js' @google-cloud/datastore `Datastore` instances seem to have no `.location` property or something similar. Also, the Google provided Datastore libraries in other languages seem to lack this functionality.

With other Google APIs you usually have a way to get the Location of the resource. E.g. in GCS: `Storage().bucket('mybucket').getMetadata().location -> 'EU'`.

[How to view Google Cloud Datastore Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260877/how-to-view-google-cloud-datastore-region) shows to get this information in a manual way, but I'm after programmatic access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore has a [database get method](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/get) (in preview as of 2021-12-23), that you can use to lookup the location of your database.  This API will also tell you the mode of your database (Firestore native vs Datastore mode).

Comment: Thanks! Database name seems to be always `(default)` so the call would be firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myProjectId/databases/(default)